# Trouble adding 2d array contents on an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a battleship game implementation with HTML/JavaScript. This function is supposed to add the positions of the ships on an HTML table by copying the elements from a 2d array(p1Board) with the positions of the ships.

```
let displayTable = () => {
        document.getElementById("player1turn").hidden = true;
        let table = document.getElementById("player1board");
        for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++){
          for(var j = 1; j < table.rows.cells; j++){
            table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = p1Board[i - 1][j - 1];
          }
        }
        document.getElementById("player1table").hidden = false;
      }
document.getElementById("p1start").addEventListener("click", displayTable);
```

Then, when I open the program on my browser, the table appears but without the positions of the ships:
[Battleship Board][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv1kA.png

Comment: Do you see any error message in the console?

Comment: No errors, just the empty table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not specifying the row from which you want to get the cells. Also, once you get the cells, you need to access their **.length** property.

**Change this line**

```
for(var j = 1; j < table.rows.cells; j++)
```

**for this**

```
for(var j = 1; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
```